# Frequency in Rutherford model of atom

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, frequency

I find the following paragraph in my book:

> In Rutherford's model of atom we assume that the elrctron revolves around the proton and the coulomb force provides the neccessary centrepetal force.But Maxwells equations show that  any accelerated electron must continously emit electromagnetic radiation.As a result energy is spent and radius of particle should gradually decrease.

Now I am curious what happens to the frequency of the electron as time passes assuming the Rutherford model of atom to be valid (although this is not the case).

A mathematical treatment: $$\text{frequency}=\frac{v}{2\pi r}$$ Now $r$ certainly decreases  as mentioned but what happens to $v$ (velocity) and how will that affect the ferquency?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this should be in comment but, As per my thought frequency is inverse proportional to the radius. if the radius is decreasing then the frequency will increase or if frequency remains the same the velocity of the electron must decrease.